# How does the organisation of classes in categories and packages work in different versions of Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, monticello

Can someone explain how the organisation of classes in Pharo works in different versions of Pharo?

- All Classes are part of the Smalltalk global (have always been, seem to stay like this?)
- Classes can have a Category, but thats only a kind of tag? (has always been, seems to stay like this? *But the categories are somehow mapped to packages sometimes*?)
- There are different kinds of Packages in different Versions of Pharo

  - MCPackages representing Monticello Packages
  - PackageInfo
  - RPackage (Pharo 1.4)?

In addition there is SystemNavigation which somehow helps navigating classes and methods based on some of the above mentioned constructs?

Comment: Perhaps someone could add a Monticello tag. I tried, but i do not have  the rights to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Classes**

The fact that classes are keys in the `Smalltalk` global is an implementation detail. As long as there is a single global namespace for class names, it is likely that the implementation will stay the same.

**Class Categories**

The class category *is* very much like a tag. A class can only be in one category at a time. Originally the class category was used by the `Browser` for organizing the classes in the system.

When `Monticello` was created, the class category was overloaded to also indicate membership in a *Monticello package* the`MCPackage` and `PackageInfo` classes were created to manage this mapping.

`PackageInfo` does all the heavy lifting: finding the classes and loose methods that belong to a package.

`MCPackage` is a Monticello-specific wrapper for `PackageInfo` that adds some protocol that wasn't necessarily appropriate for the more general `PackageInfo`.

**Packages**

Overloading the class category for package membership was a neat trick to ease the adoption of `Monticello` (existing development tools didn't need to be taught `Monticello`), however, it is still a **trick**. Not to mention the fact that the implementation of `PackageInfo` was not very efficient.

`RPackage` was created to address the performance problems of `PackageInfo` and to be used as part of the next generation of development tools.

Both package implementations will continue to exist until `PackageInfo` can be phased out.

**SystemNavigation**

As Frank says,

> SystemNavigation is a class that, as its name suggests, permits easy
>   querying of a number of different things: the classes in the image,
>   senders-of, implementors-of, information about packages loaded in the
>   image and so on.

Comment: What is the relation between a "Monticello package" and a MCPackage? By the name i assumed they were one and the same.

Comment: A Monticello package is a file with extension `.mcz`. An MCPackage is an in-image instance representing that package.

Comment: Thank you, i updated my question accordingly. So how are MCPackage and PackageInfo or MCPackage and RPackage related? Or do they just live side by side?

Answer (score 4):

Classes are, at the moment at least, the keys in the `Smalltalk` dictionary.

`PackageInfo` contains information about a grouping of classes and extensions to other packages.

A Monticello package contains a deployable unit of code. Usually one of these will correspond to a `PackageInfo` instance. (Hitting the "+Package" button in a Monticello Browser will create one of these, for instance.) A Monticello package may contain pre-load and post-load scripts, so the two classes perform separate, if related, functions.

`SystemNavigation` is a class that, as its name suggests, permits easy querying of a number of different things: the classes in the image, senders-of, implementors-of, information about packages loaded in the image and so on.