# How to split a Package/Category in Pharo 2.0 with regard to Monticello Packages

Tags: version-control, smalltalk, pharo, monticello

In Pharo 2.0 i started with Classes in one Package/Category ([I'm not sure, what is the right term in Pharo at the moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136968/how-does-the-organisation-of-classes-in-categories-and-packages-work-in-differen)). I have an identically named Monticello package which i contribute to.

Now i split the Package/Category:

- MyPackage

becomes:

- MyPackage-Core
- MyPackage-AddOns

What is the intended way to manage these Packages/Categories with Monticello now? Is there a way to automatically split the Monticello packages accordingly? (I created some mess doing it manually and ended up starting in a new image and manually filing in the classes and then creating new Monticello packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on the pharo developers mailinglist ([splitting MC packages](http://forum.world.st/splitting-MC-packages-td3740376.html)):

> > Closing the eyes and restarting from scratch. We did that too with the 
> >     Seaside packages at some point. [...]
>
> We did the same for Moose. We kind of followed this process:
>
> 1. create new sub-package XYZ-Sub*
> 2. move classes from XYZ to XYZ-Sub*
> 3. repeat until all classes and extensions from XYZ are moved away to subpackages
> 4. add the Monticello repository to XYZ-Sub*
> 5. commit all XYZ-Sub* packages. Make sure that there are no categories without packages left behind (in other words to not lose
>      code)
> 6. save the image
> 7. load in a fresh image
> 8. if problems appear, and they always appear because it is manual work, go to the previous image and recommit

Comment: I typically finish this process by create a final empty commit for the MyPackage monticello package indicating that this package is now deprecated and listing the names of the new packages.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [Monticello manual](http://www.wiresong.ca/monticello/), or perhaps it is easier to read the section on Monticello in [Pharo by Example](http://pharobyexample.org/). Deeper info is in the draft chapters in [volume 2](http://rmod.lille.inria.fr/pbe2/)

Comment: Thank you, I am familiar with the documentation. I just could not find anything regarding my problem. I thought it must be quite common?